# php-jquery autocomplete the textbox from database

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I want to auto load the text box  with some database values. I tried with following code but not getting the values for autocomplete. I used firebug to debug the script but neither it is showing error nor I am getting results.
Here is the code-

```
<script src="js/jquery1.10.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#userlist').autocomplete({

        source: function( request, response ) {
            //alert('hi')
            $.ajax({
                url : 'ajax.php',//?action=getUsers',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    name_startsWith: request.term,
                    type: 'users'
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    //alert('in');
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 0        
    });
</script>
<form action="search_result.php" name="searchform" method="post">

    <input id="userlist" type="text" class="form-control txt-auto"/>

</form>
```

Comment: What is the response from ajax.php?

Comment: I saw the Net tab in firebug, no request is generated. How can I debug it in good manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait for `$('#userlist')` to be created :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userlist').autocomplete({
        // code ...
    });
});
```